# Netlify Deployment stuck and will not deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, deployment, netlify

I have no clue what it wrong... someone please check it out! Here is the last few lines of the deployment log:

```
5:10:16 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:10:16 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
5:10:16 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:10:16 PM: ​
5:10:16 PM: $ npm start --force
5:10:17 PM: npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
5:10:17 PM: > frontend_base_dapp@0.1.0 start
5:10:17 PM: > react-scripts start
5:10:19 PM: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.4.210.17/
5:10:19 PM: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
5:10:19 PM: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /opt/build/repo/public
5:10:19 PM: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
5:10:19 PM: Starting the development server...
5:10:19 PM: 
5:10:40 PM: Compiled with warnings.
5:10:40 PM: 
5:10:40 PM: src/App.js
5:10:40 PM:   Line 2:8:  'logo' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
5:10:40 PM: src/Mint.js
5:10:40 PM:   Line 1:38:    'useRef' is defined but never used                                                                                                                                                     no-unused-vars
5:10:40 PM:   Line 97:6:    React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                             react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
5:10:40 PM:   Line 128:39:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                                                                                                    eqeqeq
5:10:40 PM:   Line 136:19:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
5:10:40 PM: src/redux/blockchain/blockchainActions.js
5:10:40 PM:   Line 47:23:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
5:10:40 PM: Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
5:10:40 PM: To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
5:38:33 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime
5:38:36 PM: Failed to compile.
5:38:36 PM: 
5:38:36 PM: ./src/index.js
5:38:36 PM: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/src/index.js'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.My deployment in netlify just gets stuck and says "
Deploy in progress"

Also, I can start a local server with `yarn start` and it works fine. This only occurs when deploying to netlify. (using react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build of your application stucks because you have errors in your code, in the log above there are printed specific lines on  which you have errors, along with description where the issues comes from. Try to fix them, then if your deployment is still stuck kill the pipeline and then deploy the new fixed version. Should work then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).